# Nesting of the conditional operator

Tags: c++

I had to make a program wherein I was supposed to take `age` and `experience`(whether the employee is experienced or not) of an employee as input from the user and print out his/her salary. The salary was subject to the following conditions:

- If employee is inexperienced, salary=2000 irrespective of age.
- **For an experienced employee:**

  - If age<=28, salary=3000.
  - If 28<age<=35, salary=4800.
  - If age>35, salary=6000.

I made the following C++ program:

```
.
.
.
  cout<<"The salary of the employee is Rs."<<(experience?sal1:2000);  //LINE1
  sal1=((age<=28)?3000:sal2);
  sal2=((age<=35)?4800:6000);

  return 0;
}
```

where `age`, `sal1`, `sal2` are declared as `int` and `experience` as `bool`.

`experience=1` is entered by user for experienced employee and otherwise `experience=0`.

But whenever `experience==1` and any `age>28` is entered, I get unexpectedly large integral results whereas the code produces absolutely perfect results when conditional operator is nested.(i.e I copy the expression of `sal1` to the *truth* expression in LINE1 and copy the expression of `sal2` into expression of `sal1`)

Please explain what is the difference between both of these codes and why am I getting unexpected results in the first case.

**NOTE**: I have used the gcc g++ compiler for compilation of my code. Please tell if it's the fault of the compiler, the operator or is there any other issue.

Comment: That code looks like it's written in reverse. You need to first calculate `sal2`, then `sal1`, and *then* you can print the value of `sal1`. (You must have some fundamental misunderstanding about what code means. I recommend a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and starting at chapter one.)

Comment: Why you do so? Is really unreadable. Make well readable inline function or lambda. I can show you an example.

Comment: You have to calculate `sal2` before you can use its value to calculate `sal1`. Programs run fron the top to the bottom.

Comment: Turn on a higher warning level and look at the compiler warnings. The compiler will warn you that you are using an uninitialzed `sal1`/that you are reading `sal1` before writing to it.

Comment: You can't print the result before you have calculated it. Not in an imperative language like `C++`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but when every you ask questions here use the [edit] functionality and the preview to improve the formatting of your question. Especially splitting a larger chunk of text into multiple blocks improves readability. And providing a [mcve] instead of writing `where age, sal1, sal2 are declared as int and experience as bool.` is also helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!@molbdnilo and galik That worked just perfectly!!!! Thank you for the suggestions @t.niese and Nick. I'll try to improve that from next time onwards

Comment: [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to understand the logic, both for writing and for reading, if you used plain `if ... else if ... else` instead.

Perhaps something like

```
int salary;
if (age <= 28)
{
    salary = 3000;
}
else if (age > 28 && age <= 35)
{
    salary = 4800;
}
else
{
    // Age must be over 35 to come here
    salary = 6000;
}
```

Comment: Looking at the error that the questioner made in his code (using result before calculating it) I doubt that your answer helps him.

Answer (score 0):

No need such a difficult to read (and write) code:

```
#include <iostream>

int calcSalary(int age, bool experience){
   if (!experience)
      return 2000;

   if (age <= 28)
      return 3000;

   if (age <= 35)
      return 4800;

   return 6000;
}

int main(){
   std::cout << "The salary of the employee is Rs." << calcSalary(36, false) << '\n';

   return 0;
}
```

Assuming C++11, you can use lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
    
int main(){
   auto calcSalary = [](int age, bool experience){
      if (!experience)
         return 2000;

      if (age <= 28)
         return 3000;

      if (age <= 35)
         return 4800;

      return 6000;
   };

   std::cout << "The salary of the employee is Rs." << calcSalary(36, false) << '\n';

   // no return 0 need for C++11
}
```

Comment: But why `inline` and why using a lambda here? Just because you CAN use something doesn't mean it's the appropriate thing to use. And you missed that there were 2 arguments instead of one. The comment about the unnecessary return is misleading for a beginner, it's just not needed for the main.

Comment: Historically `inline` means "inline the function". But nowadays `inline` helps defining the function in header file - It is not currently there, but it may be moved. Same for `static` and anonymous namespace. However anonymous namespace is bit over the top for such a small example.

Comment: There is no need for the second argument.... I think... Is very unreadable. My function do exactly what the description say.

Comment: Right, but as you said, it's in the main.cpp. So it does effectively nothing here and just adds noise for a beginner

Comment: No it does not. The OP said the salary is 2000 if the employee is inexperienced

Comment: in main.cpp `inline` do something. It prevent creating the function in the object file. If you do without, both "calcSalary" and "main" will be "exposed" in the object file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224403/discussion-between-stefan-riedel-and-nick).

Comment: `// no return 0 need for C++11` is not just confusing, strictly speaking it is wrong. The implicit return from main has nothing to do with C++11

Comment: It will be more confusing if I omit this comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use nested ternary operators (for instance if you want to use `const` everywhere), then you can do something like this:

```
auto const salary = (!isExperienced) ? 2000 :
                    (age <= 28 ) ? 3000 :
                    (age <= 35 ) ? 4800 : 6000;
```

remember that the ternary (`?`) operator works like this:

```
(conditional-statement) ? (if-true) : (if-false)
```

when you chain them together like in the example, then they are evaluated sequentially from top to bottom. So testing for `isExperience` is first, and if the employee is `NOT` experienced then we evaluate as `2000`. From there we test if `less than or equal to 28`, `less than or equal to 35`.